# How to get access token for one Soundcloud account

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I am creating an app that will only ever use one Soundcloud account, controlled by me. I am wondering if there is a way to get an access token for that one account without notifying the user. Is it possible to authorize my app for the one account, then use it from then on? I am new to API's and PHP, sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, however according to the API it is not. If you look at their documentation, [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication), and click on the tab for PHP, it says it is not supported. However, if you get the PHP wrapper for use with the SoundCloud API, found [here](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud), you can. This is the wrapper  they suggest using, but for some reason this isn't documented.

```
// create client object
$client = new SoundcloudService('client id', 'client secret');


//Get access token
$client->credentialsFlow('username', 'password');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use one SoundCloud account as a service account.

Here are the relevant Docs:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#connect

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#token